# Breeze.js getEntities returns no entity

Tags: javascript, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, breeze

Using Breeze.js coupled with an Asp.net Web Api (with Entity Framework 6 Code First) I am unabled to get entities after a call to executeQuery(query). More specifically here is my call in javascript:

```
       entityManager.executeQuery(query)
           .then(function(data){
                 alert(data.results.length); // length > 0 --> has data !!
                 alert(entityManager.getEntities().length); // == 0 has no data WHY?!!
       });
```

while executeQuery(query) does hit my api controller on the server and **returns data** to client because **data.results.length > 0**, it looks like data is not not cached because **entityManager.getEntities().length == 0**. How then can I track changes if data is not cached? Am I missing something?
After googling around I found this post http://forum.ideablade.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=3739&title=entity-manager-cache-not-working where it is said that **Simply put, Breeze requires that the models and dbcontext be in the same namespace.** Is this the issue in play here? since I cannot change my namespaces (dbcontext and api controllers come from an external library I do not have control hover) what workaround could be used in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause is that the objects returned by the server are not entity data ... at least not from the point of view of the Breeze client.

Perhaps you can show us your query.

Check out the ["Query Result Debugging" topic](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-result-debugging) in the Breeze documentation.

Comment: Yes that was exactly the cause. I added $type to my returned json and now it is working. But the way great job with breeze. We were stuck in our project until we found this framework. So far it looks like it is the tool we needed. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Great. And thank you. Curiously, what is your server tech stack? If you were using Web API, the serializer would have generated `$type` for you. Always eager to hear from folks using non-.NET technologies.

Comment: Hello! coming back to you. I'm using Web Api + Entity Framework in the backend. To fetch data I use a custom method that runs a raw sql (not linq statements but string sql statements for more flexibility and re-use ) againts the database: 
List<myDTO> data = dbContext.Set<myDTO>().sqlQuery( raw_sql ).toList(); Then I serialize it using Json.Net and add some custom header information before sending the whole packet back to the client. I guest somewhere in the process I loose the $type